# Digital code of the high reference voltage of an A/D of a microcontroller

Tags: adc

I know in theory that the digital code of \$n\$ ones (the digital code for \$V_{DD}\$) is equal to \$2^n - 1\$.

For example, the code `111` is equal to \$2^3 - 1\$ when \$n=3\$. This is because 
$$
1*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^0 = 2^3 - 1 
$$

Why does this formula always work?

Comment: I don't understand what it is you don't understand. Can you clarify?

Comment: \$1*2^2+1*2^1+1*2^0 =(2^3)-1  \$  how do you go from left to right mathematically?

Comment: I think that [this Math SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22599) has the answer you need.

Comment: Add one and watch what happens to the carries. Then note that 2^n-1 + 1 = 2^n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a mathematical problem.

the digital code of n 1's corresponds to:

$$N = 1+\color{red}{2+2^2+2^3+\cdots +2^{n-1}}\tag1$$
multiplying equation \$(1)\$ with \$2\$:
$$2N = \color{red}{2+2^2+2^3+\cdots +2^{n-1}}+2^{n}\tag2$$

\$(2)-(1)\$ will give:
$$N = 2^n -1$$

Comment: Thank you. Is there a name for this power series?

Comment: That just kicks the can down the road a bit, no? There's no proof for the bottom equivalency!

Comment: @stefandz see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: @nidhin I understand geometic series well, but your answer doesn't include the series summation formula in its generic form, so it's a bit of a tautology. A better answer would include the derivation - otherwise it looks like you just chose a neat looking way of dividing one side of the equation by one (I know you didn't, but you can hopefully understand where I am coming from).

Comment: @MaryE I think it is the geometric series.

Comment: @nidhin - do you mind if I edit your answer to include the intermediate step - i.e. the geometric progression summation general formula?

Comment: You can edit your answer and add the wiki link for future references.

Comment: @stefandz I just edited the answer. Thanks for the feedback. I thought it was obvious :)

Comment: @nidhin I think it's obvious too, but that's the really hard part about a question like this - if the OP doesn't think it's obvious, then maybe someone new won't either, so an edit like the one you just did gives them a better starting point. Also, it's more focussed on the outcome than the Math SE answer is (and less on the process) so it makes a valuable addition. Nice answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Think of numbers you are more familiar with. The number 1234 really means:

$$1 * 10^3 + 2 * 10^2 + 3 * 10^1 + 4 * 10^0$$

so: 9999 is:

$$9 * 10^3 + 9 * 10^2 + 9 * 10^1 + 9 * 10^0 = 10^5 - 1 = 10000 - 1$$

This is an example of a **decimal** power series.

The **binary** power series is the same but each column is a power of 2 higher than the previous column, instead of a power of 10

Answer (score 0):

The problem essentially boils down to performing the sum of a geometric series $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{i-1}$$ which can be found to be $$\dfrac{1(2^{n}-1)}{2-1}$$ which yields the answer.